# Turn JSON response into variables - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below script which when run makes an API call to retrieve some JSON. It works and I am happy with whats returned.

My issue is, I don't know how to turn what is returned into global variables I can use throughout my project.

To explain further, I make the call and some JSON is returned. `NAME, EMAIL, ADDRESS`

I then want to run another script which can make use of these variables. Can anyone give me an example?

```
   $('.Name').html(data.user.name);
    $('.Email').html(data.user.email);
    $('.Address').html(data.user.teams[0].name);
```

**Script**

```
  function currentUrl() {
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        chrome.tabs.query({
          active: true,
          currentWindow: true
        }, function(tabs) {
          resolve(tabs[0].url)
        })
      })
    }
    function userIdfromUrl(url) {
      var parts = url.split('/')
      return parts[parts.length - 1]
    }
    var authorizationToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    function myapiRequest(endpoint, options) {
        $.ajax($.extend({}, {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        $('.Name').html(data.user.name);
        $('.Email').html(data.user.email);
        $('.Address').html(data.user.teams[0].name);
    },
        url: "https://api.myapi.com/" + endpoint,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
          "Accept": "application/vnd.myapi+json;version=2"
        }
      },
      options));
    }
    currentUrl()
      .then(function (url) {
        return userIdfromUrl(url)
      })
      .then(function (userId) {
        return myapiRequest('users/' + userId + '?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=teams')
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.user.name)
        console.log(data.user.email)
        console.log(data.user.teams[0].name)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, define your variable : var abc = null;
In your success function, try this:  abc = data.user.email;

Answer (score 0):

You need to define global variable because you pass it to the callback function or in callback function assign it to global variable.

```
var userName;
var userEmail;
var userTeamName;
```

then in response

```
.then(function(data) {
            userName = data.user.name;
            userEmail = data.user.email;
            userTeamName = data.user.teams[0].name;
        }
```

then in your html markup:

```
$('.Name').html(userName);
$('.Email').html(userEmail);
$('.Address').html(userTeamName);
```

**Hope this helps!**